# Did Paul Offit, MD, say that aluminum plays an important role in the development of a healthy fetus?

Tags: quotes, vaccines

The following quote is attributed to Paul A. Offit, MD, by a number of websites and books; they can be found by Googling for the exact quote in quote marks (screenshot below)

> Aluminum is considered to be an essential metal with quantities
>   fluctuating naturally during normal cellular activity. It is found in
>   all tissues and is also believed to play an important role in the
>   development of a healthy fetus.

The source of the quote is given as website of Children's Hospital of Philadelphia (CHOP) Vaccine Education Center, dated in April 2013.

The closest present day webpage on this subject is http://www.chop.edu/centers-programs/vaccine-education-center/vaccine-ingredients/aluminum

I have tried to use [the "Wayback Machine" archives](https://web.archive.org/web/20130801000000*/http://www.chop.edu) to try to find this quote in original form, but have not succeeded. Thus is the temporal nature of internet publishing; contrary to the "it's out there forever" reputation.

So my question is: Did Paul Offit actually say (write) this?

---

[image: Google search]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a shorter version of the quote on an [archived version of the page](https://web.archive.org/web/20141117042412/http://vec.chop.edu:80/service/vaccine-education-center/vaccine-safety/vaccine-ingredients/aluminum.html) from November 17, 2014:

> Aluminum quantities fluctuate naturally during normal cellular activity. It is found in all tissues and is also believed to play an important role in the development of a healthy fetus.

As you can see at the bottom, it says "Reviewed by: Paul A. Offit, MD / Date: March 2014".

According to a comment [here](https://community.babycenter.com/post/a55469728/dr_suzanne_humphries._aluminum_is_toxic_to_all_life_forms_the_case_against_aluminum_in_vaccines.), this is an *updated* version of the page. The archives don't go back that far though. However, the fact that people were quoting the longer wording as far back as [2011](https://respectfulinsolence.com/2011/12/28/jenny-mccarthy-plans-to-promote-antivaccine/) gives credibility to it being genuine.